# How to define an automorphism for $S_3 \times C_8$ in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Consider the group $W:= S_3 \times C_8$. How can I define an automorphism for $W$? For example 
$f:W ‎\longrightarrow‎ W$; $f(x,y)=(x,y^{5}g(x))$ where $g:S_3 ‎\longrightarrow‎ C_2$ is defined as follows: $g(\sigma)=y^4$ if $\sigma$ is even and $g(\sigma)=id$ if $\sigma$ is odd, $x$ is arbitrary element of $S_3$, $y$ is an arbitrary element of $C_8$, and $a$ is the generator of $C_8$.

Comment: Are you looking for a certain automorphism or??

Comment: This question could used some [edit]ing.  Presumably $g$ has domain $S_3$ (rather than $C_8$) since $x \in S_3$ and $C_2$ is the subgroup of order $2$ in $C_8$.  What is $5i$?  What does "How can defined automorphism for $W$?" mean?  How $f$ does relate to the question?  What does this have to do with GAP?

Comment: One could create group automorphism in GAP using `GroupHomomorphismByImages` and `GroupHomomorphismByFunction`. It may be possible to provide a concrete example for your problem, but could you please first edit the question responding to remarks by @DouglasS.Stones ?

Comment: @HosseinShabani: I've modified the question to give an answer. Hope you could now create another automorphisms by example - please ask if you will have further questions.

Comment: Why do you ask such this questions at this site and left the answers unaccepted, Hossein???!!!

Answer (score 5):

The question has been unedited within 20 days. I've modified it trying to make the notation consistent enough to give an answer.

First, let's create our groups:

```
gap> S3:=SymmetricGroup(3);
Sym( [ 1 .. 3 ] )
gap> C8:=CyclicGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> G:=DirectProduct(S3,C8);
<group of size 48 with 5 generators>
gap> Size(G);
48
```

Now, for a direct product there are associated `Projection` and `Embedding` operations:

```
gap> x:=Random(G);
DirectProductElement( [ (1,3), f1*f3 ] )
gap> Image(Projection(G,2),x);
f1*f3
gap> Image(Projection(G,1),x);
(1,3)
gap> Image(Embedding(G,1),(1,2,3));
DirectProductElement( [ (1,2,3), <identity> of ... ] )
gap> Image(Embedding(G,2),GeneratorsOfGroup(C8)[1]);
DirectProductElement( [ (), f1 ] )
```

We shall use these operations to construct $f$ from the question, but first we need to define $g$:

```
gap> g:=function(x) 
> if SignPerm(x)=1 then 
>   return GeneratorsOfGroup(C8)[1]^4;
> else
>   return One(C8);
> fi;  
> end;    
function( x ) ... end
```

Now create `f` as follows:

```
gap> f:=function(h)
> local p1, p2, e1, e2, x, y;
> p1:=Projection(G,1);
> p2:=Projection(G,2);
> e1:=Embedding(G,1);
> e2:=Embedding(G,2);
> x:=h^p1;
> y:=h^p2;
> return x^e1 * (y^5*g(x))^e2;
> end;
function( h ) ... end
```

Then call `GroupHomomorphismByFunction`:

```
gap> aut:=GroupHomomorphismByFunction(G,G,f);
MappingByFunction( <group of size 48 with 5 generators>, 
<group of size 48 with 5 generators>, function( h ) ... end )
```

**Attention**: It is documented in `GroupHomomorphismByFunction` entry in the GAP manual that "No test is performed on whether the functions actually give an homomorphism between both groups because this would require testing the full multiplication table."

In this case we may check it ourselves and see that `f` is not a homomorphism at all:

```
gap> ForAll(Tuples(G,2),t -> t[1]^aut*t[2]^aut = (t[1]*t[2])^aut);
false
```

Oops! Let's modify $f$ as follows: $f(x,y) = (x,a^4 y g(x))$:

```
gap> f1:=function(h)
> local p1, p2, e1, e2, x, y, a;
> p1:=Projection(G,1);
> p2:=Projection(G,2);
> e1:=Embedding(G,1);
> e2:=Embedding(G,2);
> x:=h^p1;
> y:=h^p2;
> a:=GeneratorsOfGroup(C8)[1];
> return x^e1 * (a^4*y*g(x))^e2;
> end;
function( h ) ... end
```

and try to create another homomorphism:

```
gap> aut1:=GroupHomomorphismByFunction(G,G,f1);
MappingByFunction( <group of size 48 with 5 generators>, 
<group of size 48 with 5     generators>, function( h ) ... end )
```

Now we have an automorphism:

```
gap> ForAll(Tuples(G,2),t -> t[1]^aut1*t[2]^aut1 = (t[1]*t[2])^aut1);
true
gap> Source(aut1)=G;
true
gap> Image(aut1)=G;
true
```

Moreover, it is properly recognised as an element of `AutomorphismGroup(G)`:

```
gap> A:=AutomorphismGroup(G);
<group of size 48 with 5 generators>
gap> aut1 in A;
true
```

**Remark**: as we may see, it is potentially unsafe to use `GroupHomomorphismByFunction` since it returns a `MappingByFunction` and does not check whether it is a homomoprhism. To use it, one has to be sure that the mapping indeed is a homomorphism. I'd prefer to use `GroupHomomorphismByImages` where images of generators would be calculated using functions similar to `f` above (which may also take extra arguments in this case, since it does not need to comply with `GroupHomomorphismByFunction` syntax). A simple example is:

```
gap> gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(G);;
gap> aut2:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(G,G,gens,List(gens,w->w^aut1));
[ DirectProductElement( [ (1,2,3), <identity> of ... ] ), 
  DirectProductElement( [ (1,2), <identity> of ... ] ), DirectProductElement( [ (), f1 ] ), 
  DirectProductElement( [ (), f2 ] ), DirectProductElement( [ (), f3 ] ) ] -> 
[ DirectProductElement( [ (1,2,3), <identity> of ... ] ), DirectProductElement( [ (1,2), f3 ] ), 
  DirectProductElement( [ (), f1 ] ), DirectProductElement( [ (), f2 ] ), 
  DirectProductElement( [ (), f3 ] ) ]
```

Now we see that it works with `aut1`, but it does not work with `aut` which is not a homomorphism:

```
gap> aut3:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(G,G,gens,List(gens,w->w^aut));
fail
```

It remains only to check that

```
gap> Image(aut2)=G;
true
```

to see that we've constructed the desired automorphism. And indeed,

```
gap> aut2 in A;
true
```